# Python:Generate a variable inside a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, image-processing, image-generation

I am trying to generate and save an image with a new name for each loop.Is this possible in python with a for loop?Or should I try a different approach?

```
For i in range(x,y)
 i=str(i)
 p= img(i).save(s+i+j,)
 i=int('i')
 i=i+1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from PIL import Image

images = [...]

# create some images 

for i, image in enumerate(images):
    image.save('image_%03d.png' % i)
```

Comment: I did not know that Image supports indexing

Comment: @GeorgeNostradamos You didn't know it, and you don't know it now. `img` is a list. Note the list notation `[...]` whereby Dombi meant that you get a list of 10 images.

Comment: So what he wrote could easily be described like this (input my images inside a list and then just put an index). I understood that, it was clear, I mean he could just write it, not that I am not grateful that he gave me the code, what I don't understand is why are you explaining it to me when the code is talking by itself.Either way thanks to both of you for your time.

P.S I did not mean to offend you, what so ever.So, sorry if you get offended.